# Increase the main tableview row height according to the custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I am having an app in which I have a **Tableview** and on that tableview's each row I am dynamically creating a custom tableview cell.

Below is the code for that.

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"flowviewTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

cell2 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

return cell2;
```

"FlowTableViewCell" is a UITableViewCell. **In this custom cell, I have one tableview.**

I am showing some data on my custom tableview cell from an array and those data varies in length. It is not fixed.

**I am able to increase the custom cell size but not the main tableview row height depending upon the size of custom tableview cell.**

**I want to increase the height of the main tableview's cell size dynamically depending upon the size of custom tableview cell.**

With the following code, the height of the custom tableView cell is increasing.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *str = [arrComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSLog(@"%f",size.height);
    if (size.height<20)

    {
        size.height=20;
        //m= size.height;

    }

    NSLog(@"%f",size.height);

    return size.height +  30;


}
```

How can I adjust the height of main tableview's row height depending on the size of custom tableviewcell?

Here,I am attaching some of the screenshots for clear understanding.

The following is my custom TableViewCell:

[image: Custom TableViewCell]

The following is my main TableView :

[image: Main TableView]

Following is the output I am getting right now:

[image: output getting right now]

You can see in the above image that comment2 gets cut and comment3 of the same post gets displayed in the next post.

I want output like  following Image.

[image]

**So,my question is how can I increase the height of the main tableview's cell size dynamically depending upon the size of custom tableview cell?**

Please help me.any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to adjust the height dynamically. First you need to determine the height of the label and then adjust the height of the cell accordingly. I have been using this code in my chat application and works fine.

First, create the label and image view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
            /// Set Text Label

            UILabel *lbl_myText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [lbl_myText setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            lbl_myText.minimumScaleFactor = FONT_SIZE;
            [lbl_myText setNumberOfLines:0];
            lbl_myText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            [lbl_myText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

            NSString *text = [arr_text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

            // Checks if text is multi-line
            if (size.width > lbl_myText.bounds.size.width)
            {
                CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f); //// Here Width = Width you want to define for the label in its frame. The height of the label will be adjusted according to this.

                //CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

                NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

                paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;


                CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy}
                                                     context:nil];

                CGSize size = textRect.size;

                [lbl_myText setText:text];
                [lbl_myText setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.imgv_someoneImage.frame.size.width+8, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - cell.imgv_someoneImage.frame.size.width -(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];
            }

            else
            {
                lbl_myText.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, cell.frame.size.width - cell.imgv_someoneImage.frame.size.width - 18,18);
                lbl_myText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                [lbl_myText setText:text];
            }

            //lbl_myText.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_myText];

            /// Set Date Label

            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
            NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[arr_date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

            UILabel *lbl_myDate = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.imgv_someoneImage.frame.size.width+8, lbl_myText.frame.size.height+10, cell.frame.size.width - cell.imgv_someoneImage.frame.size.width - 10 ,18)];
            lbl_myDate.text = stringFromDate;
            lbl_myDate.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:13.0];
            lbl_myDate.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            lbl_myDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_myDate];

            /// Set User Image

            UIImageView *imgv_myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, lbl_myText.frame.origin.y, 63, 63)];
            imgv_myImage.image = selectedUserUploadedImage;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgv_myImage];
}
```

Here define some of the constants:

```
#define FONT_SIZE 15.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f /// change this according to your screen size. This is just an example
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 10.0f
```

Now, after creating the labels, you will have to determine the height of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [arr_text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSString *cellDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[arr_date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   // NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    //CGSize labelsize = [cellText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    ////for message label
    CGRect textRect = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy}
                                         context:nil];

    CGSize labelsize = textRect.size;

    ////for date label
    CGRect datetextRect = [cellDate boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy}
                                             context:nil];

    CGSize datelabelsize = datetextRect.size;


    //CGSize datelabelsize = [cellDate sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    ///combine the height
    CGFloat height = MAX(labelsize.height + datelabelsize.height, 64.0f);

    if(height == 64.0f)
    {
       return 74; /// label is of one line, return original/ static height of the cell
    }

    else
    {
        return height + 10; /// label is of multi-line, return calculated height of the cell + some buffer height 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the Height of Label using:

```
- (CGRect)heightOfLabel:(UILabel*)resizableLable
 {
    CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(resizableLable.frame.size.width  , 9999);

        NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                              nil];

        NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"textToShow" attributes:attributesDictionary];

        CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil

        ];


        if (requiredHeight.size.width > self.resizableLable.frame.size.width) {
            requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0, self.resizableLable.frame.size.width, requiredHeight.size.height);
        }

      return requiredHeight;
    }
```

Call this method from TableView delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   return [self heightOfLabel:cell.textLabel];

}
```

Comment: in which method should i write this & what should i return?

Comment: Both methods have to be inserted into your UITableViewController class. The first is a normal method which calculates a CGRect, the second one is a method of UITableViewDelegate

Comment: It gives me this error `Returning 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect') from a function with incompatible result type 'CGFloat' (aka 'float')`.

Comment: please help me. too many research on this.your coding is not working for me.

Comment: can you pls explain the issue u r facing

Comment: If u can come up please join me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63839/room-for-maulik-shah-and-satish-azad

Comment: I'll explain you what i want exactly and where i am stuck ri8 now.

Comment: @SatishAzad i am waiting for you.

Comment: @MaulikShah: yes I am available on stack overflow chat now

Comment: hey i am available.let's chat

Comment: Buggy code. App is crashing at  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *str = [arrComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
CGRect new = [str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(280, 999) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil];
CGSize size= new.size;
NSLog(@"%f",size.height);
if (size.height<20)

{
    size.height=20;
    //m= size.height;

}

NSLog(@"%f",size.height);

return size.height +  30;


}
```

Comment: If you have two labels in the row you have to add both labels height and check whether you are getting correct string value NSString *str = [arrComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; by placing NSLog and check the size.height for that 'str' value in NSLog

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

1. Create a common `UITableViewCell` subclass for all the cells in your view (such as `FlowViewAbstractTableViewCell`)
2. Create a class method on the table view cell subclass such as `+ (CGFloat)sizeForCellWithComment:(Comment *)comment`. What you're doing is setting up a method to pass a model object into that each table view cell subclass can implement.
3. Create however many other cell subclasses you need that inherit from `FlowViewAbstractTableViewCell`. In your case, it looks like you could have ones called `FlowViewTextCommentTableViewCell` and `FlowViewPictureCommentTableViewCell`.
4. For each of those subclasses, implement that `+sizeForCellWithComment:` method. This will allow you to return a variable size based on the object you pass into the method.
5. Implement `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` for your `UITableViewDelegate`. In this method you are going to figure out which cell class you want to use and which object to pass into that size method. For example:

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   Comment *commentForCell = [self.comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return [CommentTableViewCell sizeForComment:commentForCell].height;
}`

This will allow you to return a variable cell height based on the object. I use variably sized table view cells all the time & love this pattern because I think it does the best job of hiding the implementation and following MVC.

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KImie4ZMwk) gives a great tutorial on using autolayout to dynamically size UITableViewCells. When I needed to do this for an application I ended up subclassing UITableViewCell and setting my constraints programmatically, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Very simpler [solution](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/) than the above

Comment: Try customizing your UITableViewCell rather than using the predefined one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return [self.tableName.dataSource tableView:self.tableName cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].contentView.frame.size.height;
}
```

And in your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate if you are using label
then first set number of lines to label as 0, then set label text and then add sizeTofit property of it. Like this

```
 [cell.yourLabelName setNumberOfLines:0];
 cell.yourLabelName.text = @"Your long or short text";
 [cell.yourLabelName sizeToFit];
```

This will expand your label height as per the text in it.

After that you can set the size of your cell contentView like this.

```
 cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width,"Height of label" + cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
```