# create a simple chat view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, chat

I need to create a simple chat view in which i can show messages from two ends (sender and receiver) like any Message App .

What i have done till now is , created a `UITableView` , A `UIButton` and a `UITextField`. And on that UIButton tap , i am adding UITextField text to array , Now I need the second end also like in ours Messaging app (sender side).

Left side is receiver and Right side is sender.

My app till now looks like

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

messageLabel = nil;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    messageLabel.tag = 101;
    [cell.contentView addSubview: messageLabel];

      } else {


    messageLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 101];

      }    //---calculate the height for the label---
int labelHeight = [self labelHeight:[listOfMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
labelHeight -= bubbleFragment_height;
if (labelHeight<0) labelHeight = 0;

messageLabel.frame =
CGRectMake(bubble_x + 10, bubble_y + 5,
           (bubbleFragment_width * 3) - 25,
           (bubbleFragment_height * 2) + labelHeight - 10);

messageLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
messageLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
messageLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

messageLabel.text = [listOfMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

return cell;
}

-(void) sendAction:(id) sender {
[listOfMessages addObject:field.text];

[chatTable reloadData];
field.text = @"";

[field resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: You have to create two custom cell and take two array one for sender and second for receiver and both cell have different cell identifier as mrunal and  rubin said your problem will solve

Comment: its being very easy to create Nib for the cells otherwise you have to maintain single `UITableViewCell` and it will be bit complex. So its a suggestion to a developer from all the developer.

Comment: can't we create it by code? ? @ Jay

Comment: Ya you can create but it will be bit complex for you and also complex from my side to explain every steps

Comment: Ok then , How to use Nib file,

Comment: in that you have to manage frames of message label and profile pic every time.

Comment: rubin says whole steps you just create two xib with its .h and .m file and its super class select `UITableViewCell`

Comment: And ya don't forget about to create your label and profile pic outlet as a `@property`  in cell's .h file. So you can access it from your view controller.

Comment: Ok ,, I ll try n come back.,, Thnkzz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91554/discussion-between-jay-raparka-and-ammy).

Comment: @SaurabhDutta have u resolved ur issue. can u share ur workign code for ur prob

Comment: @SaurabhDutta u there could u tell, how have u did

Comment: @imran - You can use accepted answer . It is working fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take two different custom cells one for the sender and one for the receiver like this:

[image: for sender]

1. for Sender

[image: for receiver]

2. for Receiver

Now, in your app, there must be login and sign-up process as it is a chat app and there will be server associated with your app to save data.

What you can do is that, when you send the message, also send the name of the receiver with it and store it in your database.

Now, in your chat view, fetch all the message data, along with the receiver names.

Fetch the `userName` who is currently logged in during the Login process.

You can do something like this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *myArrayElement = [arr_receiverUserName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //do something useful with myArrayElement

    if(![myArrayElement isEqualToString:userName])
    {
         /// These are my messages.
         //// Pop up 'mycell' here 

            UILabel *lbl_myText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [lbl_myText setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            lbl_myText.minimumScaleFactor = FONT_SIZE;
            [lbl_myText setNumberOfLines:0];
            lbl_myText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
            [lbl_myText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

            NSString *text = [arr_text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

            // Checks if text is multi-line
            if (size.width > lbl_myText.bounds.size.width)
            {
                CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

                CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

                [lbl_myText setText:text];
                [lbl_myText setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - cell.imgv_myImage.frame.size.width -(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];
            }

            else
            {
                lbl_myText.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, cell.frame.size.width - cell.imgv_myImage.frame.size.width - 18,18);
                lbl_myText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
                [lbl_myText setText:text];
            }

            //lbl_myText.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_myText];

    }

    else
    {
        //// These are the messages sent by some one else

       /// Pop up `someonecell` here

        UILabel *lbl_myText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [lbl_myText setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        lbl_myText.minimumScaleFactor = FONT_SIZE;
        [lbl_myText setNumberOfLines:0];
        lbl_myText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [lbl_myText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

        NSString *text = [arr_text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

        // Checks if text is multi-line
        if (size.width > lbl_myText.bounds.size.width)
        {
            CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

            CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            [lbl_myText setText:text];
            [lbl_myText setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.imgv_someoneImage.frame.size.width+8, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - cell.imgv_someoneImage.frame.size.width -(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];
        }

        else
        {
            lbl_myText.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, cell.frame.size.width - cell.imgv_someoneImage.frame.size.width - 18,18);
            lbl_myText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            [lbl_myText setText:text];
        }

        //lbl_myText.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_myText];

    }
```

You can do similar things for images and audios.

---

For **Dynamic Height Of The Cell:**

To make  to the height of your cell according to your `UILabels`, refer to [Increase the main tableview row height according to the custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210816/increase-the-main-tableview-row-height-according-to-the-custom-cell/33006937#33006937)

Comment: I am not using nibs or storyboard , Can you tell me by code How to implement it

Comment: I have updated the answer... But why you want to make things difficult for yourself... if you can do it using nibs or storyboard?

Comment: I have never used nib files. So, I was asking .. But i ll try to use nibs alos

Comment: I have added both the things in the answer. You will need both.

Comment: Ok ,, Ill  try n come back ... Thanks Rumin

Comment: Hi Rumin  , I have been able to implement this with two custom cells on two different nib files . How to set labels frame , So that it will become equivalent to the text size .

Comment: Hello @Ammy I have already answered that thing here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210816/increase-the-main-tableview-row-height-according-to-the-custom-cell/33006937#33006937... Let me know if you have any problem, implementing it.

Comment: Thanks but the my labels frames are not updating . I dont know whats wrong .? I have added two nibs and just dragged two labels on  it and make their OutLet

Comment: Create those label programmatically as I have done. You will be through with it. I was also stuck with the same problem earlier as you are facing now. I ended up doing it programmatically and it works. Moreover, the text will be dynamic so it is better to do it in that way.

Comment: Glad to help you Ammy.. if the answer in the link was also helpful to you, you can vote it as useful there also! :)

Comment: @RoOmin hi have u have any sample project for settign chat left and right

Comment: @SaurabhDutta...Hi I'm also implementing same feature...Please provide sample code if u implemented. thanks in advance

Comment: @Rumin...I'm also implementing same chat feature...Please provide sample code if possible for above explanation...thanks in advance

Comment: @Priya Here are the links [Chat Demo](https://github.com/rumin26/chatDemoAppplication) and [Tinder Demo](https://github.com/rumin26/Marvel-DC-Tinder). The first one may be outdated because of Parse dependency but you can refer the code and get the idea.

Comment: @Rumin...Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create multiple cell with different CellIdentifier For Example. Cell For sender and receiver. And you can subdivide it in categories like text,audio,video,image.

**Download sample ChatUI Demo (Objective-C & Swift) from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K6mm83zblcIakaENvsM7R0CEEaLzUnGO)**

Lets have example for the text chat.

First of all you need to create 2 cell prototypes in your Storyboard or XIB with different CellIdentifier for example "`cellSender`" and "`cellReceiver`".

Take `UILabel` or `UITextView` inside cell and for `cellSender`  make left alignment and for `cellReceiver` make the alignment right for making different layout for sender and receiver.

Then You can do with following with your code...

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL sender = NO;

// Check for the sender or receiver 
    <code for checking message is from sender or receiver>

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = sender?@"cellSender":@"cellReceiver";

    messageLabel = nil;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        messageLabel.tag = 101;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: messageLabel];

          } else {


        messageLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 101];

          }    //---calculate the height for the label---
    int labelHeight = [self labelHeight:[listOfMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    labelHeight -= bubbleFragment_height;
    if (labelHeight<0) labelHeight = 0;

    messageLabel.frame =
    CGRectMake(bubble_x + 10, bubble_y + 5,
               (bubbleFragment_width * 3) - 25,
               (bubbleFragment_height * 2) + labelHeight - 10);

    messageLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
    messageLabel.backgroundColor = sender? [UIColor greenColor]: [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    messageLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    messageLabel.text = [listOfMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
    }
```

**EDIT**

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]

Comment: How to create  2 cell prototypes . As i am not using StoryBoard or Xibs

Comment: Hi mural , I have been able to implement this with two custom cells on two different nib files . How to set labels frame , So that it will become equivalent to the text size .

Comment: @mrunal thanki....Please provide sample code for above explanation...i'm also required same feature

Comment: Hi @Priya, You can find demo for simple chat UI from my above edits.

Comment: @mrunalthanki...please update in Objective-C.Thanks in advance

Comment: @Priya I have added Objective-C code in same link. You can download it from above link.

Comment: @mrunalthanki...Thank you so much...Must appreciate for quick reply

Comment: @mrunalthanki...How to display the receiver message at left side (Response from server like :: success - true / success - false. if success -true show in collection view  / If success - false display in tableview cell at left side)

Comment: @Priya added UICollectionView in UITableViewCell..Please download demo and check it.

Comment: @mrunalthanki...How can i Updated the UI with a Text field sir